# Unknown array in where clause

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter

I get the error unknown array in where clause. I know that the $project is an array but how can i fix this problem in the where clause?(i am using codeigniter).

```
<?php

function rapport_detail_opbrengsten($idKlant) {
    $this->db->from('Project');
    $this->db->join('Opbrengsten', 'Opbrengsten.idProject = Project.idProject');
    if ($idKlant > 0) {
        $this->db->where('idKlant', $idKlant);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $project = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $project[] = $row->idProject;
    }
    $test[] = $project;

    $this->db->select('idProject, SUM(Prijs) as total');
    $this->db->from('Opbrengsten');
    $this->db->where_in('idProject', $test);
    $this->db->group_by('idProject');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: On which line you are getting error?

Comment: The line with where_in('idProject',$test);

Comment: Can you do `print_r($test)` above that line?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 14 [2] => 14 [3] => 81 [4] => 81 [5] => 81 [6] => 14 [7] => 9 [8] => 15 [9] => 11 [10] => 12 [11] => 6 [12] => 6 [13] => 6 [14] => 6 ) )

Comment: i know its an array but i would like to use all the array values for the where in variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `$test[0]` instead of `$test`